# Why in this code, await is not blocking ui in flutter

Tags: multithreading, flutter, dart, async-await

In the default example app whenever you create new fultter project I just added the following code.

```
  initState() {
    super.initState();
    loop();
  }

  loop() async {
    while (true) {
      await Future.delayed(Duration(milliseconds: 10));
      print("count now:$_counter");
    }
  }
```

1. Why is the app UI is not getting blocked? I am able to click + button and the counter increases smoothly. Even if I change the delay to 10 sec, the UI is resposive.
   Is the loop() runnning in different thread?but I know dart is single thread. How is it possible?
2. Where the loop function is running?
3. Can I use this technique to run background task for example checking id my sqflite table rows are synced with cloud etc???

Comment: 3). No, try ocupy the CPU with something else than simple "wait" and you will see the different

Comment: `await` is just syntactic sugar for registering completion callbacks on the `Future`.

Answer (score 13):

Await calls are non-blocking.
The way this works is, while Dart is single-threaded, some Dart code delegate their implementation to the Dart VM.

Things like file reads or HTTP requests are performed outside of Dart (either by the browser or in c++), in a different thread.

So while Dart is single-threaded, it is still able to perform multiple tasks simultaneously without locking the UI.

Comment: The case is different with native android by the way. Could you help explain the difference in what's happening in both the cases?

Comment: Isn't it related to the nature of the Event Loop rather than another thread or handling request outside Dart?